# converting acceleration into displacement by using cumtrapz

Tags: python, scipy

I have a list of data, which represents acceleration.

I tried to transfer acceleration into velocity and displacement by python.

But it showed the data length error when it transfer velocity into displacement.

Here are the whole code, how to fix this?

```
import scipy.integrate as it

time = [1,2,3,4,5]
acceleration = [1,2,3,4,5]
velocity = it.cumtrapz(acceleration,time)
location = it.cumtrapz(velocity,time)
print('velocity: ', velocity)
print('location: ', location)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basing on [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.cumtrapz.html) You need to set initial starting point, because `cumtrapz` is returning list with one value less then initial:

```
velocity = it.cumtrapz(acceleration,time, initial=0)
```